# Java generic function fail to compile: need interface type

Tags: java, generics, enums, compilation, extends

I'm trying a sample code snippet from "Effective Java, item 34". I'm using jdk1.8 on win10.

```
package mygroup;

import java.util.*;
public class ExtendsEnum {
    private static enum Operation {
        Plus,
        Minus;
    }
    public static <T extends Enum<T> & Operation> // error
    void testEnumClass(Class<T> opSet) {
        for (Operation op : opSet.getEnumConstants()) {
            System.out.println(op);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExtendsEnum.testEnumClass(Operation.class);
    }
}
```

Compiler says: needs interface type.
I'm not sure if my program on the problem line is still valid in jdk1.8, I just tried to copy from the book's sample code.
Does jdk recognize:

```
<T extends Enum<T> & Operation>
```

If not, how to fix it?

Comment: What is the point of `<T extends Enum<T> & Operation>`? If you expect T to represent Enum which will also be Operation then only enum which can fulfill this condition is `Operation` itself. So your method could use `Operation` instead of generic type like `public static void testEnumClass(Class<Operation> opSet)`. OR since inside you just want to iterate over values of `Operation` simply use `for (Operation op : Operation.values()){..}` and your method will not need any argument at all.

Answer (score 4):

When using `&` in generic bounds, only the first part may be a class. Everything else must be an interface. `Operation` isn't an interface, that's why it fails.

But your example makes no sense. There is only one type that matches `T extends Enum<T> & Operation`, and that's `Operation` itself. Why use a generic type anyway?

The following would be possible (yes, `OperationEnum` is a terrible name):

```
interface Operation { /* some methods */ }
enum OperationEnum implements Operation { /* constants, methods from Operation */ }
```

But unless you define an interface that actually adds methods that aren't already in enums (like `name()` and `ordinal()`), there's no need to use a stronger bound than just `T extends Enum<T>`.